# Scaling ImageView on bottom of Layout

Tags: android, layout, imageview, scaling

I try to make a Layout with two TextViews on top and an ImageView on the bottom of the Layout. But I have problems with the scalingtyp of the ImageView. The Image should always resize propotional but be always on the center buttom. Here is a picture with my problem:

[image: Layout]

I hope you unterstand my problem.
Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/transparent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewGameOver1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewGameOver2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewGameOver1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewGameOver"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewGameOver2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
    android:src="@drawable/sheldon_win" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Have anybody a idea to solve this problem?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout`.  This will let you position the image where you want it and then you can set the size of the `ImageView` to be whatever size you want.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewGameOver"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/sheldon_win" />
```

This should put the image in the lower-right corner and the image should be whatever size the image file is.  If you want to change that you can set the width and height to some size in dp's.

Comment: I also tried it with a RelativLayout, but the result is the same. I have edited my code above.

Comment: That's not surprising given the settings you have for the `ImageView`.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but now the image is not scaling. If the texts from the TextViews are very large, the ImageView should scaling down.